# Call jQuery function on object dynamically created by Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [this Bootstrap plugin](https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/) to turn a checkbox into a pair of buttons. It works as expected when the checkbox exists before the page is loaded (part of page's initial HTML); however, I need it to run when a checkbox is dynamically created by Angular, as it is when editIndex is set, as in the function below:

```
ModalController.prototype.edit = function($index)
{
    this.editIndex = $index;
    $(":checkbox").checkboxpicker();
}
```

When I call the function above, the function that actually creates the buttons isn't called; it appears to be deferred. How can I call the function that actually creates the buttons on a checkbox created after the page was loaded?

Comment: You might want to try to create new directives in angular to create your buttons and checkboxes.

Comment: *checkbox is dynamically created*  means it is created via loop ? or directives ? please provide some codes or fiddle thanks

Comment: @kiro112: It's included in a script tag so that it can be used when angular creates a modal. That's why it doesn't exist on the DOM when the page is first loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be fine using the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service to delay the execution of `$(":checkbox").checkboxpicker();` until angular has finished rendering the template.

```
ModalController.prototype.edit = function($index)
{
    this.editIndex = $index;
    $timeout(function(){
        $(":checkbox").checkboxpicker();
    });
}
```

Creating a custom directive for the checkboxpicker might be a better solution, though. Something like

```
myApp.directive('checkboxPicker', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el){
            $(el).checkboxpicker();
        }
    }
});
```

And then use it in the template like `<input type="checkbox" checkbox-picker>`

Comment: The first approach didn't appear to work, but the second one did. Thank you!

Comment: The second approach is a much more Angular way of doing it. Any time you want custom javascript bound to a DOM element, make a directive.